# Experience builder standard Login Form component ignores startUrl parameter

Tags: experience-builder-page

Why does the standard Login Form component in Experience Builder Sites ignore the 'startUrl' parameter? No matter what I enter for the parameter it always goes to the home page. Am I missing something? I did some rough debugging on it and what I could glean was that the component has the correct value at a certain point for the parameter, but it gets overridden by a handler of an event called 'e.siteforce:registerQueryEventMap'. I couldn't find a single piece of information about this event online. Any kind of help is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This scenario was reported by other end users too and the Salesforce Product development team has filed a documentation bug #W-9464156 to add a note to the 'Start URL' property for the 'Login Form' component, to indicate that it will not override the startURL query string if present: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.rss_login_form.htm&type=5

Here's a little background:

1. The 'startURL' property specified in the LoginForm component will not and does not override the 'startURL' query string parameter if one is provided when the page is loaded. The value specified in the component properties will only be used if their is no 'startURL' query string present in the URL. This is by design.
2. For any URL, if the target page is not accessible to a user, it will direct the user to the site's configured login page, and the startURL parameter will become the path of page the user tried to access. For example, if I tried to access the private page "https://xxxx.force.com/mysite/s/mypage" without being authenticated, it would be expected that you'll get directed to the site login page, where the startURL will be "/mysite/s/mypage", and after login you'll be directed to that page. This is the reason by why the 'startURL' property configured in the loginForm component should never override the query string parameter (1). Overriding the query string parameter would break this very vital and important part of the auth process.
3. If customers require the 'startURL' parameter to be overridden for all scenarios, then they could modify the CommunitiesLogin apex controller, and/or create a custom lightning login component.

Example scenario:

1. An unauthenticated user accessed a page on the site that requires authentication.
2. This correctly directs the user to the site login page, including the startURL query string parameter for the original page (#1).
3. After the user authenticated, they were directed to the page indicated by the startURL query string parameter, as opposed to the page configured in the 'Start URL' property of the Login Form component.

The above scenario is working as designed, where that 'Start URL' property would only be used if the 'startURL' query string parameter is not present in the current URL.

Comment: I figured this might be the case, but in my scenario even if I go directly to the login site without trying to access any specific page the system will automatically append the '/s' to the startUrl parameter. How do I override that?